# Using custom pipe in angular 2, unable to load the data on load of the html throws error cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular

My template:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let abcList of abcLists | filterdata: srchTerm; let i = index">
  {{abcList .name}}
</tbody>`
```

Data of abcLists:

```
abcLists = [
  {
    'id': 1,
    'date': '02/04/2017',
    'name': 'The Hero',
    'size': '1.8 GB',
    'network': 'hfg',
    'services': 'wughf',
    'content_owner': 'Any',
    'contact_email': 'iwygf'
  }]
```

And custom filter

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterdata'
})
export class FilterPipeComponent implements PipeTransform {

  transform (value: any[], args: any[]){
    const search = args[0].value;
    console.log(search)
    if (!search) return value;

    return value.filter(item => 
      (item.name == search || item.services == search || 
      item.content_type == search || 
      item.network == search || item.size == search 
      || item.service == search)
    );
  }
}
```

On loading the component on console error is thrown as :

> abcComponent - inline template:56:27 caused by: Cannot read property
>   '0' of undefined

Comment: Post the component that's feeding that template

Comment: Sonicd300 actually I have hardcoded the data abcLists within the component itself, sorry forgot to mention

Comment: Pipe also must assert that value is not null or undefined. `If (!value) return value` or return `[]`

Comment: Anton Lee could you please explain, thanks, thats what I am not able to figure out is it due to pipe or *ngFor :)

Comment: you don't have a second parameter for your pipe at your template `*ngFor="let abcList of abcLists | filterdata: srchTerm; let i = index">`. So `args ` in your pipe will be undefined.

Comment: as @Pengyy sais you dont need for arrays of args in your case, just `arg: string`

Comment: @Anton Lee my args can be of any length actually so please suggest :)

Comment: @Pengyy I may have an array of values or single value for args so how to handle it :)

Comment: what kind of objects you have in args? do you have `value` property in it?
try `...args: any[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `...agrs` for uncertain counts of parameters. But **you have to handle the non parameter branch** anyway, also check whether the parameter exists before using it.

see below example:

```js
function test(...args) {
  console.log(args.length);
}


test();

test('a');

test('a', 'b');

test('a', 'b', 'c');
```

---

Add a sample for using `Array.some` in `Array.filter` in order to filter multiple keywords.

```js
function tranform(input, args) {
  return input.filter(item => {
    return args.some(arg => {
      return item.field1 === arg || item.field2 === arg;
    });
  });
}

var arr = [
  {
    field1: 'test1',
    field2: 'test2'
  },{
    field1: 'test11',
    field2: 'test22'
  },{
    field1: 'test33',
    field2: 'test44'
  }
];

console.log(tranform(arr, ['test1', 'test11']));
```

Comment: hmm ok I'll try it out, I had tried handelling for undefined or null , will try again and update here, thanks alot

Comment: @Enthu take your time. Hope this will help. :-)

Comment: Hi @Pengyy I would receive args = This is it    or        args = ["Japan", "America"] in this format and I need to handle the undefined args as well so that on load my value is returned as it is

Comment: I am not able to return the data(value) as it is on load, and it throws undefined

Comment: how do I conver the args to a single string if it is single value and if it is array of values then iterate over it and pass in both the cases the single value as string and array of values to filter method

Comment: @Enthu IMO, maybe you can define the parameter as `any` type, and check its instance in your filter function.

Comment: Yes now I am checking but last issue is how to apply the array values to filter , as in  ["Japan", "America"] applying it to filters?

Comment: @Enthu sorry, your question is unclear to me. please explain the word `apply`. do you mean for `transform`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152697/discussion-between-enthu-and-pengyy).

Comment: Thanks alot @Pengyy :), I had implemented using for loop but this is a more readable code to write

Answer (score 0):

your srchTerm must be a string not an array.

You can use the filter like this.
`<div *ngFor="let abcList of (abcLists | srchTerm)">
  {{abcList.name}}
</div>`